# Headless chrome browser getting an error on hover drop down menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
            options.addArguments("headless");
            
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Error Message:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
(Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
...
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at seleniumgluecode.common.user_navigate_to_and_click_view_all_promotions(common.java:748)